# How to get a class to print out multiple parameters (__str__ function question)

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, class

I'm creating a class that prints out its contents using the **str**() function. However, I can only seem to be able to get it to print out one of the parameters? When I ask it to return self.num as well as self.word it throws an error.

Would anyone be able to help me on this?

```
class Test:
    def __init__ (self, word, num):
        self.word = word
        self.num = num

    def __str__(self):
        return self.word, self.num

a = Test('Word', '10')
print(a)
```

Comment: `__str__` must return a str; it cannot return a tuple. You'll have to create a string of them first.

Comment: Do you know how to format *one string* of several variables?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, I don't know how to format one string of several variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `__str__` method is expected to return a single string. To show several variables, concatenate (via `+` if they are strings) or format them (via [f-string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings), [format string templates](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings), or [printf %-formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting)) into a single string.

```
class Test:
    def __init__ (self, word, num):
        self.word = word
        self.num = num

    def __str__(self):
        # f-string literal - ``{...}`` are replacement fields
        return f'{self.word} => {self.num}'

a = Test('Word', '10')
print(a)  # Word => 10
```

Comment: Thanks that works! I'm not sure I totally understand it (I don't know what concatenate means) but I'm still a beginner and I can look into it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: To concatenate means to create a new string by attaching two existing strings to each other. For example, your could define ``__str__`` to ``return self.word + self.num``. Note that you generally cannot concatenate other types to a string, for example ``'Word' + 10`` will not work (note that the ``10`` is not quoted - it is an integer number).

Comment: @saeley7 Glad to have helped. Please consider to upvote and/or accept this answer if it solves your problem. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for details.